# «Toute LA vie» vs «toute UNE vie»

Tags: articles

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre les expressions «toute la vie» et «toute une vie» ? Est-ce que le changement d'article affecte également le sens ?

Comment: Cela va fortement dépendre du contexte. As-tu des exemples de phrases complètes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les deux formes expriment deux choses connectées mais différentes, cependant selon le contexte c'est parfois l'une des deux qui convient et pas l'autre. « Toute la vie » tend à caractériser une longueur de temps correspondant à la vie qui reste à quelqu'un qui est un adulte, sans spécification d'âge et c'est souvent employé comme une exagération pour insister sur l'aspect interminable de quelque chose ; on pourrait même l'employer pour qualifier une action à laquelle se livre une personne de 95 ans. Mais c'est une expression qui peut aussi signifier « le temps de vie entière dont dispose quelqu'un ». « Une vie » réfère assez fidèlement à la durée dune vie humaine en général.

- Ça va te prendre toute la vie et tu n'auras toujours pas un bon résultat ; je crois qu'il vaut mieux que tu fasses cela à peu près, sans te tracasser.
  *« Une » ne convient pas bien ici.*

  *Cependant, on peut dire ceci ;*

  - Ça prend toute une vie et tu n'auras jamais un bon résultat ; je crois qu'il vaut mieux que tu fasses cela à peu près, sans te tracasser.
    *« une vie » réfère à la vie moyenne d'une personne, c'est à dire toute la durée d'une vie moyenne, et est utilisé pour donner une mesure du temps nécessaire. On ne considère plus l'action sous l'aspect de la personne qui en est l'agent mais seulement sous l'aspect de la chose en elle-même ; en d'autres mots on ne dit pas « ça va te prendre trop de temps » mais « ça prend trop de temps à tout le monde ».*
    *Néanmoins il est encore possible d'écrire cela comme suit ;*
  - Ça prend toute la vie et tu n'auras jamais […].
- Il faut toute la vie pour vraiment bien parler trois langues.
  *la vie de quelqu'un en général, et l'on entend « vie » donc comme  « durée moyenne d'une vie »*
- Il faut toute une vie pour vraiment bien parler trois langues.
  *la vie de qui que ce soit, en général, le temps moyen d'une vie*
- Je ne vais pas y passer toute la vie, c'est assez maintenant, fini de polir ces essais.
  *On ne dira pas « toute une vie » dans le présent cas. « Toute la vie » est utilisé, en tant qu'exagération, pour insister sur le temps démesurément long que prend quelque chose.*
- Vous y aurez passé **toute une vie/la vie** et vous aurez toujours des difficultés à bien comprendre tout ce que vous pouvez lire dans ce domaine, tellement il y a d'information.
  *Le temps complet de la vie de quelqu'un, le temps de vie restant à une personne en général, pas un vieillard ; comme il s'agit d'une réflexion sur un état de chose en général  les deux formes sont possibles et on n'insiste pas sur la différence entre une période absolue (toute une vie) et une période qui ne prend pas tout à fait en compte la totalité; c'est donc un contexte où « toute la vie » équivaut pratiquement à « la vie entière d'une personne ».*

Comment: Quelle merveilleuse réponse, merci infiniment ! Les explications et les exemples sont très clairs, merci !